# Button issues in HTML

Tags: html

this is our code; we tried to link a page with a button, but the page is not opening,instead after clicking the button it redirects to the same page as the button.
The code for the button is:

```
<a href="search.html"><div class="form-group">
<button name="signup" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Send Query</button></div></a>
```

Please help us debug this.

Comment: Beacuse you are using href tag and button tag in same time.

Comment: why are you using the button `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`?

Comment: change the type of the button from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and make sure if the page you are linking is located in the same folder where the page of the button is.

Comment: both `type=submit` and `type=button` should work here

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add your css classes on the link so it looks like a button `<a href="search.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Send Query</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all, try this code,

```
<a href="search.html"class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Send Query</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have placed the files in same directory?

And then Try this code :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <a href="search.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Signup</a>
 </div>
```

Then you may give your anchor tag look and feel same like button.